# Kivy Textinput not detecting physical keyboard on Windows

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to design a simple application using Kivy and Python 3.7 with a Textinput. I managed to hide the virtual keyboard using `textinput.keyboard_mode="managed"`. However, when typing on the physical keyboard I get no text showing in the focused text box although I have set the keyboard to system `Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'system')`. The program is below

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem, MDList
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem, IconLeftWidget
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
Window.size = (1920, 1080)
Window.fullscreen = True
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'system')

class StudentApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        superBox = BoxLayout(orientation ='vertical')
        toolbar=MDToolbar(title="Student Call List", anchor_title= "center" )
        toolbar.md_bg_color=[0.5, 0, 1, 1]
        superBox.add_widget(toolbar)
        # Creating a Simple List
        textfield=TextInput()
        textfield.keyboard_mode="managed"
        textfield.use_handles=True
        superBox.add_widget(textfield)
        scroll = ScrollView()
        list_view = MDList()
        
        for i in range(5):
            icons = IconLeftWidget(icon="android")
            items = OneLineIconListItem(text=str(i) + ' item')
            items.add_widget(icons)
            list_view.add_widget(items)
            
        scroll.add_widget(list_view)
        # End List
        superBox.add_widget(scroll)
        screen.add_widget(superBox)
        return screen
    
  
StudentApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyboard_mode="managed"` requires setting the keyboard visibility manually, or calling the helper functions `show_keyboard()` and `hide_keyboard()`

You can remove this line - `textfield.keyboard_mode = "managed"` or add `textfield.show_keyboard()` after it.
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.html#kivy.uix.behaviors.FocusBehavior.keyboard_mode